# How to create a bar chart from an excel file into R?

Tags: r, bar-chart, fixed-point, excel-tables

I am new to the R software and playing with a different dataset. But recently I am facing a problem in creating Barplots where I do not have the original dataset but have the outcome e.g. percentage, frequency of that dataset of different variables.

The dataset of mine looked like this in the excel file. I want to create a stacked or grouped bar chart with this information and compare the depression level between the 2 universities. In the depression level, the first value represents to NSU and the 2nd value represents to DIU.

```
University:  NSU, DIU;
No Depression: 59.7%, 40.3%
; Mild: 55.2%, 44.8%
; Moderate: 51.1%, 48.9%
; Mod.Severe: 53.3%, 46.7%
; Severe: 50%, 50%
```

I have tried to create a data frame with the information I have. And succeded to create a barplot from that too. But I am not satisfied with that. I want to have a more specific graphical representation.

```
mydf <- data.frame( Normal=c(NSU=59.7, DIU=40.3), 
  Mild=c(55.2,44.8), 
  Moderate = c(51.1,48.9), 
  ModeratelySevere=c(53.3,46.7), 
  Severe = c(50,50))

barplot(t(as.matrix(mydf)), beside=TRUE)
```

I got a barplot from this way but they are separated into two groups. All the depression level of NSU in One side and all the depression level of DIU on another side.

[image: My outcome]

But I want to present each of the depression levels by their university. That means, In X-axis there will be 5 levels. Normal, Mild, Moderate, Mod. Sever, Severe. And each level will present 2 of the universities students depression level.

[image: My Expected Graph]

Comment: remove the t from your barplot statement,  `barplot(as.matrix(mydf), beside=TRUE)`

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively using ggplot and tidyr:

```
library(ggplot2)
library(tidyr) #For gather

mydf <- data.frame( University = c("NSU", "DIU"),
                    Normal=c(59.7,40.3), 
                    Mild=c(55.2,44.8), 
                    Moderate = c(51.1,48.9), 
                    ModeratelySevere=c(53.3,46.7), 
                    Severe = c(50,50))


mydf %>% 
  gather(Depression, Level, -University) %>% 
  ggplot(aes(Depression, Level, fill = University, group = University)) +
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = "dodge")
```

Comment: @Scott-U solved my prev prob. I've tried to create the data frame in a different way to practice your method and got an error.

> df2 = data.frame (Depression = c("Normal","Mild", "Moderate", "Moderately Severe", "Severe"), Percent =c(19.9, 36.9, 34.8, 5.4, 2.8))

> df2%>% gather (Depression, Level, -Percent) %>%+ ggplot (aes(Depression, Level, fill=Percent, group=Percent))+geom_bar(stat="identity", position ="dodge")

Error: `data` must be a data frame, or other object coercible by `fortify()`, not an S3 object with class uneval. Did you accidentally pass `aes()` to the `data` argument?

Comment: The way you've defined `df2` sounds like it's already in long form and need not / cannot be gathered. The `ggplot` call expects to see a `University` and `Level` variable but your table doesn't have those.